# Analytical Expression for Moment of Generalized chi-squared distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moments, chi-squared-distribution

Consider $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and the moments:
$$
E\left[ \left(C_1(Z+\sqrt{\lambda})^2 - C_2\right)^t\right].
$$
Here, $C_1$, $\lambda$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants which are all positive. $t$ is a nonnegative integer. *Is there an analytical form for these moments in terms of $t$, $\lambda$, $C_1$ and $C_2$?*

So far, I have identified that $C_1(A+\sqrt{\lambda})^2 + C_2$ follows a [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution). Where, following the notation on the wiki, $k=1$, $\lambda = \lambda$, $w = C_1$, $m=C_2$, $s=0$. However, I do not see any analytical expression for the moments on the wiki.

I see there are analytical moments for the [noncentral chi-squared distribution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NoncentralChi-SquaredDistribution.html). I also know how the moment generating function of the noncentral chi-squared distribution can be used to obtain moments for the generalized chi-squared distribution. However, I am able to obtain an analytical expressions using that approach.

Comment: I imagine lambda is positive, is t as well, or either C for that matter?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica could not solve this integral, even with the assumptions that t and lambda > 0. (Edit: Integral t doesn't help either, unfortunately).

Comment: Assuming $t$ is a *non-negative* integer, expand the argument as a polynomial in $Z$ and apply linearity of expectation.

Comment: Thank you for that last comment. I will post an answer below. I feel that this is the correct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion provided by @whuber:
$$
\left(C_1(A + \sqrt{\lambda})^2-C_2\right)^t = \sum_{k=0}^t\text{nCr}(t, k)\left(C_1(A + \sqrt{\lambda})^2\right)^k\left(-C_2\right)^{t-k}
$$
Then apply the expectation operator:
$$
\text{E}\left[\left(C_1(A + \sqrt{\lambda})^2+C_2\right)^t\right] = \sum_{k=0}^t\text{nCr}(t, k)C_1^k\text{E}\left[\left((A + \sqrt{\lambda})^2\right)^k\right]\left(-C_2\right)^{t-k}
$$

Note that $\text{E}\left[\left((A + \sqrt{\lambda})^2\right)^k\right]$ is the $k$-th moment of a noncentral chi-squared distribution with analytical form reported [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NoncentralChi-SquaredDistribution.html).